# Run a command after an amount of time (js)

Tags: javascript, triggers, bots, discord, discord.js

I've seen things like Interval, but I don't quite understand it, especially in my use case scenario. (semi-new to JS)

I'm creating a Discord.JS bot, and for the economy system, I'm trying to make a loan function. The loan function will need to take back the coins + interest that was invested, and the maximum loan time is one day. I just need to know how to:

1. Make the function so that it triggers after the provided amount of time;
2. Allows the function to run again (if two people loan at the same time), it still works.

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

```js
let millisecondsDelay = 5000; // 5 seconds

setTimeout(function()
{
  alert("After waiting 5 seconds, now I alert.");
},millisecondsDelay);
```

If you wrap the code above into a function of your own, that same delay will happen independently for each call of that wrapper function.

```
function myCustomFunction()
{
    let millisecondsDelay = 5000; // 5 seconds

    setTimeout(function()
    {
      alert("After waiting 5 seconds, now I alert.");
    },millisecondsDelay);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!